# REST style API returns 404 when identifier value contains special characters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

We have a Web API endpoint defined as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("orders")]
public class OrdersStatusController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("{referenceId}/status")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> StatusByReferenceIdAsync(
        [Required] string referenceId)
```

Up until now the referenceId value has been pretty simple, so we see calls along the lines of:

> https://foo.bar/orders/20210903074937/status

Recently we encountered a situation where the referenceId contained special characters, such as `srn::orders:/1801001003`.

> https://foo.bar/orders/srn::orders:/1801001003/status

Obviously that's not going to work as the slash in the referenceId messes up the URL. Our initial thought was to have the caller URL encode the referenceId value. Now the call becomes:

> https://foo.bar/orders/srn%3A%3Aorders%3A%2F1801001003/status

However, when using that URL we get a 404 from the application.

We've tried adding the following to the web.config but the behavior remains.

Other similar questions have answers suggesting adding a wildcard to the variable.

```
    [HttpGet, Route("{*referenceId}/status")]
```

However that results in a run-time error stating that the wildcard must be the last segment of the URL.

We don't control the caller so a custom encoding isn't really an option, nor is disallowing certain characters in the referenceId.

Comment: What if you don't encode the /?

Comment: Can you use something other than slash, or just decode it before using it?